# Python - Firefox Selenium 'Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location'

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to scrape a website which uses JavaScript to display some of the text. I found out that I should be using Selenium WebDrivers instead of requests.get(), so I tried to use PhantomJS WebDriver, this didnt work however as whenever I tried to scrape this website it would scrape it successfully, but the website would produce HTML along the lines of this:

```
<p>Could not find page</p>
```

So Im guessing for some reason the WebDriver wasn't working properly. I am now trying to use the FireFox WebDriver -- Geckodriver. The path to the .exe is in my PATH, but when I run this command in python

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

It spits out the error of "Could not find specified geckodriver.exe in PATH". So instead of that, I used executable_path argument in Firefox() so it looked like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path/to/geckodriver/')
```

When I run it now, it opens geckodriver.exe (doesn't show anything on the cmd prompt screen) and spits out this error in IDLE:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to     find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.
```

However, when I try to use ChromDriver it works fine. I dont understand why this one works and others dont?

**Questions**:

1. Why isn't PhantomJS working?
2. Why isn't GeckoDriver working?
3. Why does ChromeDriver work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually about browser binary, but not about `geckodriver`. Try to use following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```